# Segfault while reading from a big collection of files

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have this method: (it's supposed to create a inverted list from all the files in the given directory)

```
class Index{
public:
  Index();
  void create();
  void writeInvertedIndex();
private:
  bool isWhiteSpace(const char ch);
  std::map<std::string, std::set<int>> invertedIndex;
};

 void Index::create(){
  std::string datasetPath = "/home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/dataset/";
  std::string filePath, word, text;
  std::ifstream infile;
  int fileIndex = 0;
  std::size_t textLen, i;
  DIR * dir;
  struct dirent * ent;
  if ((dir = opendir (datasetPath.c_str())) != NULL){
    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
      filePath = datasetPath + ent->d_name;
      std::cout << filePath << std::endl;
      std::ifstream inFile(filePath, std::ios::in);
      std::stringstream buffer;
      buffer << inFile.rdbuf();
      std::string text = buffer.str();
      inFile.close();
      textLen = text.size();
      i = 19;
      while (i < textLen){
        word = "";
        while(isWhiteSpace(text[i])){
          i++;
        }
        while(!isWhiteSpace(text[i])){
          word = word + text[i];
          i++;
        }
        invertedIndex[word].insert(fileIndex);
      }
      fileIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the program on a small collection of files (around 50Kb of text) it works fine, but when I run it on the real collection (500 files around 1.5Mb in total) it segfaults after processing around 50 files. The output inverted index is about 900Kb.

I suppose that loading the whole file into a string is not an ideal solution (the files are 1-5Kb each) but I'm using a similar approach in other parts of the project and it works fine even on the whole collection.

Could you suggest where is the problem? Or maybe give me some advice on optimization?

The weirdest thing about this is that when I run it with Valgrind it processes the whole collection without segfaulting. This is the Valgrind output:

```
==9952== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==9952==    at 0x57F6610: __writev_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so)
==9952==    by 0x4EEC4B1: std::__basic_file<char>::xsputn_2(char const*, long, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F29BC1: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F4E063: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x401BFC: Index::writeInvertedIndex() (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x4021D0: main (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==  Address 0x6f929f4 is 84 bytes inside a block of size 2,273 alloc'd
==9952==    at 0x4C2E1CA: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==9952==    by 0x4F62144: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F6219E: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x404A5F: std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, 0ul>(std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&, std::tuple<>&, std::_Index_tuple<0ul>, std::_Index_tuple<>) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x404782: std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<>) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x40458C: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >::construct<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >*, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x404247: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > > >::construct<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >*, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x403C6C: void std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >::_M_construct_node<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >*, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x403069: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >::_M_create_node<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x402C4D: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x4028A4: std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x40203A: Index::create() (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952== 
==9952== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==9952==    at 0x57F6610: __writev_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.25.so)
==9952==    by 0x4EEC4B1: std::__basic_file<char>::xsputn_2(char const*, long, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F29BC1: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F42581: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F4E564: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x401C82: Index::writeInvertedIndex() (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x4021D0: main (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==  Address 0x5d0f861 is 721 bytes inside a block of size 8,192 alloc'd
==9952==    at 0x4C2E8B7: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==9952==    by 0x4F2AA87: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_allocate_internal_buffer() (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F2EC71: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x4F2ED92: std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24)
==9952==    by 0x401B75: Index::writeInvertedIndex() (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952==    by 0x4021D0: main (in /home/skluzada/Downloads/BI-VWM/Project/index)
==9952== 
==9952== 
==9952== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9952==     in use at exit: 32,816 bytes in 1 blocks
==9952==   total heap usage: 820,861 allocs, 820,860 frees, 16,188,505,659 bytes allocated
==9952== 
==9952== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9952==    definitely lost: 32,816 bytes in 1 blocks
==9952==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9952==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9952==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9952==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9952== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==9952== 
==9952== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9952== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==9952== ERROR SUMMARY: 681764 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: It seems the crashes happen in `Index::writeInvertedIndex()`, so it might be good show that function. And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (with emphasis on the *minimal* and *complete* bits).

Comment: Why don't you check `i < textLen` in `while(isWhiteSpace(text[i])){i++;}` and in next while loop, you probably read data out of range. Change to `while (i < textLen && isWhiteSpace[text[i]]){i++;}` and do the same in second loop.

Comment: @rafix07 That was the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the asked question is the comment from rafix07:

> Why don't you check `i < textLen` in `while(isWhiteSpace(text[i])){i++;}` and in next while loop, you probably read data out of range. Change to `while (i < textLen && isWhiteSpace[text[i]]){i++;}` and do the same in second loop.

Comment: And what exactly is this answer supposed to do?

Comment: @FeiXiang Fix the segfault problem, caused by an out of range array access. What is the point of your comment? You may edit the answer, if something is missing, instead of just unclear commenting.

Comment: You basically just copied a comment already posted below the question. This does not add any new information at all. You should at least make it a community wiki since it contains none of your own work.